# Search function - problem with whole words

Tags: ajax, search

First of all, I use Timber (TWIG) with WordPress.

I created a search query in Ajax. Everything works fine but the results do not suit me. Sometimes the results show me part of the words

Example : if I write "**jour**" I got "au**jour**d'hui" like result.

I would like to have as result only the whole words.

After doing my research here. It's indicated to use `'exact' => 1`

I tried it in my query but now I no longer have any results (0 result)
at each search whereas before I had the good results.

Do you have any idea about what's wrong ? Thank you.

### script.js

```
$('#search-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var searchValue = $('#search-input').val();

    if (searchValue.length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                'action' : 'datas_fetch',
                'terms' : searchValue
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#fetch-list').html(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {

            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#fetch-list').html('');
    }
});
```

### functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_datas_fetch', 'datas_fetch' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_datas_fetch', 'datas_fetch' );

function datas_fetch() {
    $context['page_search'] = true;
    $context['terms'] = isset($_POST['terms']) ? $_POST['terms'] : '';

    $posts_types_selected = array('pages' => 'page', 'articles' => 'post', 'videos' => 'videos', 'podcasts' => 'podcasts');

    $exclude_posts = get_field('search_exclude','option');

    if ($_POST['terms']) {
        $context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => array_values($posts_types_selected),
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'paged' => 1,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post__not_in' => array_values($exclude_posts),
            'hide_empty' => true,
            'has_password' => FALSE,
            's' => $context['terms'],
            'exact' => 1
        ));
    } else {
        $context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => array_values($posts_types_selected),
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'paged' => 1,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post__not_in' => array_values($exclude_posts),
            'hide_empty' => true,
            'has_password' => FALSE
        ));
    }

    Timber::render( 'bloc_fetch.twig', $context );

    die();
}
```

### search.twig

```
<form role="search" id="search-form">
    <input type="text" id="search-input" class="search__input" placeholder="{{ __('Rechercher des articles, vidéos...', 'cmd') }}" value="">
    <input type="submit" id="search-submit" class="search__button" value="Rechercher">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Exact means exactly that - the whole field must match, not just a word in the field.

To get whole words that are part of the field,
remove  `'exact' => 1`

Add this

```
if ($_POST['terms']) {
     $keyword = sanitize_text_field( $context['terms'] );
     $keyword =  '[[:<:]]' . $keyword . '[[:>:]]';
     $context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts(array(
         // other params here
         's' => $keyword,
         // etc
```

Suggestion: use the wp_rest_api instead of admin ajax.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried and unfortunately 's' => '% ' . sanitize_text_field( $context['terms'] ) . ' %', doesn't work. I always got results with "aujourd'hui" for example. Search return results only in posts. Before I had results from pages, posts and custom post typ

Comment: Edited my answer to use regex - but it may not work with `get_posts`.

Comment: Thank you again for this new solution. Unfortunately I got 0 result now. Do you think I should use something other than `get_posts` ?

Comment: You could try using WP_Query directly.  For whole word search, I use  custom sql: `$wpdb->get_col` with the regex to collect the post ids and then WP_Query with `post__in`.  I've never used Timber.

Comment: Okay I'm interesting with this solution. I think this is because of Timber